# My project is successfully running on the apache tomcat version 6 but showing Json error while running on apache tomcat server v.6 using linux hosting

Tags: java, javascript, apache, tomcat6

This is the error displayed:

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
> type Exception report
> message Unable to compile class for JSP:
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
> exception
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
> The type org.json.JSONArray cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
> An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
> The type org.json.JSONObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Please help me to correct it.

Comment: Your server is missing a .jar file that's present on your local installation.

Comment: How can i add json.jar file to the hosting server?

Comment: You should be able to put it in your .war or .ear file, in a "lib" subdirectory. Are you bundling any other libraries?